# Does angular require reflectmetadata.js and emitDecoratorMetadata : true?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
package.json

{ "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "basic-app",
  "devDependencies": { "typescript": "^2.4.1" },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/common": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.5",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1"
 }}

tsconfig.json

{ "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": false, // set to false
  "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
}}

index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="src/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('main').catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <my-app>Loading</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

The code seems to work fine when I run it in browser; I did not include reflect metadata.js nor I have included the `emitDecoratorMetadata` property in tsconfig.json; so reflectmetadata.js and `emitDecoratorMetadata` are optional in angular2? Please let me know why the above code is still working in browser. Any help is greatly appreciated.

https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview&show=app%2Fapp.component.ts angular sample code does not include reflect metadata.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**emitDecoratorMetadata**

This setting is required to be set to `true` if you use types as tokens like this:

```
constructor(dependency: ClassName) {}
```

If it's set to `true` the compiler generates the following:

```
AppComponent = __decorate([
    core_1.Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        ...
    }),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [core_1.Injector])
                                       ^^^
                         here the type for token is referenced
```

If you only use `@Inject()` decorator, then you don't the `emitDecoratorMetadata` setting.

**Reflect metadata**

This package by itself is not usually required since it's included into `core.js` that is required by Angular:

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer. Didn't realise it was using the _decorate() function. Thought it would have just been using Class.name or something